# XCode 4.2 clang seg fault

Tags: xcode4, clang, xcode4.2

Just upgraded to Lion and xcode 4.2.  Now when I recompile my program I getting these errors:

1. `/Users/XXX/Code/iPhone/XXX/Code/Scenes/GameScene.mm:1806:35: current parser token ';'`
2. `/Users/XXX/Code/iPhone/XXX/Code/Scenes/GameScene.mm:1762:1: parsing Objective-C method 'updateWithTouchLocationMoved:withEvent:view:'`
3. `/Users/XXX/Code/iPhone/XXX/Code/Scenes/GameScene.mm:1762:1: in compound statement ('{}')`
4. `/Users/XXX/Code/iPhone/XXX/Code/Scenes/GameScene.mm:1771:2: in compound statement ('{}')`
5. `/Users/XXX/Code/iPhone/XXX/Code/Scenes/GameScene.mm:1789:3: in compound statement ('{}')`
6. `/Users/XXX/Code/iPhone/XXX/Code/Scenes/GameScene.mm:1796:4: in compound statement ('{}')`
7. `/Users/XXX/Code/iPhone/XXX/Code/Scenes/GameScene.mm:1799:5: in compound statement ('{}')`
   `clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11`
   `clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal 2 (use -v to see invocation)`

There is nothing odd going on around those line numbers.  No compound statements, just simple if `(a == b)` type stuff.  Some of the error line numbers aren't even on statements, just blank lines or a { brace.  I suspect that the line numbers are not accurate.  I'm kind of dead in the water now.  Code compiled fine under 4.1.

Any advice?

Comment: Possibly belongs on SuperUser - not really a programming question, just that the program which fails happens to be a programming tool.

Comment: @Inerdia, programming tool questions are on-topic here: [... if your question generally covers ... software tools commonly used by programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Answer (score 2):

I stopped the compiler from crashing.  After commenting out line after line of code to see where this was actually happening I arrived at this line:

```
shape.shapeType |= kTypeBreakable;
```

Doing...

```
shape.shapeType = shape.shapeType | kTypeBreakable;
```

...compiles fine.  So does...

```
shape.shapeType |= 0x00000200;
```

`kTypeBreakable` is an enum that is set to `0x00000200`

`shapeType` is just a obj-c object variable with a getter/setting.

Very very odd compiler bug.

Comment: If you're interested in getting the issue fixed, please file a report at bugreporter.apple.com.